# Python, make the script not stop while waiting for input

Tags: python

```py
def inputs():
    input("")
    #anything here waits until input
```

Is there a way of not waiting for input and continuing?
I need to check the screen width in another function while also being able to enter commands.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @user10987432 I am trying to have a check running for checking the window resolution while also having the ability to input.

Comment: Remove `input("")`?

Comment: @Ch3steR How can I write text from CMD and use it in the code again?

Comment: @MiranDaniel, Be a bit more specific. Why should you want to do both of those things at the same time? Are you asking how to create a GUI with multiple threads?

Comment: @user10987432 I am trying to have a divider over the whole console, so I get the width and write that many =. It refreshes automatically so it is always not too long or short. I want to be able to have the option to enter commands while it does the checking without it waiting for my input.

Comment: So, you want the divider to resize itself (add or take away '='s) whenever the console gets resized? That seems tricky. My first instinct would be to somehow hook the window's `resize` event and trigger a callback - if you're using IDLE you may be able to get a handle on the IDLE window using tkinter (since IDLE uses tkinter). Otherwise, if you're using the windows terminal, you would have to mess around with the windows API - I'm not saying it's even possible. Also, you'd have to move the terminal cursor over your divider line to replace the old characters, which seems icky. Maybe try ncurses

Comment: window's resize event would be awesome, thanks for the idea. I will have a look at it

Comment: Check out this blog post: https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/ here they explain what method to use for solving what problem when you think you need concurrency (like you do).

Comment: thanks a lot! helped